# Docker - Writing python output to a csv file in the current working directory

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I want to learn how to deploy applications using Docker and I'm working with this simple python program that writes some data into a csv file in the current working directory. I can see the output.csv file in the current working directory on my local machine but having trouble with it when I run the docker image.

After reading various articles and posts on stackoverflow, mounting the local directory path using "-v" seems to be the way to achieve this but I am unable get the right command.
I tried creating a new directory on my local machine named "output_docker" ( I also replaced the get.cwd() option in the program with this path)  and use that with the -v option.

```
 docker container run -v "/Users/Desktop/output_docker" docker_image_name
```

Python code (scraper.py)

```
import pandas as pd
import os

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

dirpath = os.getcwd()
print("dirpath = ", dirpath, "\n")

output_path = os.path.join(dirpath,'output.csv')
print(output_path,"\n")

df.to_csv(output_path)
```

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3
ADD scraper.py /
RUN pip install pandas
CMD ["python3","./scraper.py"]
```

Output on local machine

```
$python3 scraper.py
   Name  Age
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14

dirpath =  /Users/Prathusha/Desktop/topos_docker 

/Users/Prathusha/Desktop/topos_docker/output.csv
```

Output when I run the docker image

```
$docker build -t ex_scraper .
$docker run ex_scraper
   Name  Age
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
dirpath =  / 

/output.csv
```

I understand that the "output.csv" file will be located within the subdirectories of the docker container, but I want it to be visible in the current working directory(or desktop) when the docker image is run on a different machine.
Would appreciate if anyone can point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Files created inside the container, stay inside unless they are volume mapped outside. If you want to access the file created inside docker from the machine running the container. You could mount the working directory inside the container with `-v $pwd:/` in the `docker run` command

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can bind your host directory, I would suggest using a `WORKDIR` & replace `ADD` with `COPY`  -

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /mydata
COPY scraper.py ./
RUN pip install pandas
CMD ["python3","./scraper.py"]
```

Run it -

```
docker run -v ${PWD}:/data ex_scraper
```

You should now be able to see the CSV in your current directory on host.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You can try using `-v` during docker run, it will solve your problem.